# How can I overlay an image (exported via ArcGIS API) on an OpenStreetMap map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, leaflet, openstreetmap, layers, export

Before I attempt to explain my situation, I'd like to disclose I'm *very* new to these apps and GIS in general.

There's a public ArgGIS server that I'd like to export a layer from and overlay on an OpenStreetMap map enabled by Leaflet. I've queried the API using the `/export` REST endpoint with the following parameters:

```
'dpi': '96',
'transparent': 'true',
'format': 'png8',
'layers': 'show:37,38,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47',
'bbox': '-11872625.905327085,6573201.834478498,-6540378.812154609,7566271.705959245',
'bboxSR': '102100',
'imageSR': '102100',
'size': '1090,203',
'_ts': '1547504829299',
'f': 'image'
```

This generates a png that represents the layers I'm interested in. However, I'm having trouble overlaying on the map. I think the confusion is between `bbox` and `lat/long` coordinate systems. I'm not sure how to properly center the image on the map so the overlay works. I'm also not able to get it to zoom in properly on the OSM map.

I've tried the following configuration using Leaflet:

```
var imglayer = './layer.png';
var imgbounds = [[-11872625.905327085,6573201.834478498],[-6540378.812154609,7566271.705959245]];
L.imageOverlay(imglayer, imgbounds).addTo(mymap);
```

But the image isn't even visible.

Comment: If your code is copy/paste then one thing is definitely wrong: `imageUrl` in `L.imageOverlay` call should be `imglayer`.

Comment: @TomazicM, I should have copy/pasted...I just transcribed wrong.

Comment: What is your crs?

Comment: The CRS is `ESRI:102100` (`bboxSR`) http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6928/

Comment: ...which [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection#Other_identifiers) is `EPSG:3857`.

Comment: @fglleo7 Leaflet uses `EPSG:3857` as the [default coordinate system](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-crs). Thus you must pass the coordinates in the range of [-90°,90°] for latitude and [-180°,180°] for longitude.

Comment: @Stefan, I tried changing the `bboxSR` to `3857` and I'm now not getting an image back. Is there a calculator to convert the `102100` system to `3857`?

Comment: Apparently they are the same, but you need decimal degrees in both cases, according to the ArcGIS REST API. Why are you not querying in decimal degrees in the first place?

Comment: Request parameters: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/export-image.htm#GUID-52ECA75B-80FC-4036-96C7-5E0AC8791697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L.imageLayer` requires LatLng bounds (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#imageoverlay). To convert projected coordinates to LatLng, you can use `map.options.crs.projection.unproject(point)`, or in your case `L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(point)`, where point must be `L.point`.

So your image bounds definition should look something like:

```
var imgbounds = [
  L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(L.point([-11872625.905327085,6573201.834478498])),
  L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(L.point([-6540378.812154609,7566271.705959245]))
];
```

Comment: I think that this unprojects pixel values on the canvas into geographic coordinates. See https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#point

Comment: @Stefan That is true for `map.unproject`.

Comment: Wow, cool, I just tested this and the result is `LatLng(50.727326, -106.653613),LatLng(56.039443, -58.753223)`! :D

Answer (score -1):

If you are new to GIS it isn't always a great idea to dive straight into web mapping:
I would
 - getting the overlay (png) into a GIS Software package. I'd suggest QGIS 2.18 - it's free (https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)
Next add anything else you want to see in GIS
Then create a leaflet site using GIS2WEB plugin in QGIS (https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_plugins/fetching_plugins.html)

These tools will allow you to overlay what you want and so you can at least get a visual idea of what you want to look at rather than trying to 'do it blind' in leaflet.